# Passing flash messages to the database (express.js + mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm using a module called "express-flash-2" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash-2)

As you can see in the docs, there's an example link which is https://github.com/jack2gs/express-flash-2/tree/master/examples/express4

I have around 35 flash messages in my website and I've created a partial file called "flash.ejs" and passed all the flash messages to it.

Here's a flash message example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="error-box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon_close"></i></a>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body modal-body-info">
        <p>Server error, please try again.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And this one's at the bottom of the file:

```
  <% if( flash.error){%>
  $('#error-box').modal('show')
  <%}%>
```

There are around 35 of these with different flash message names (error, success, loginrequired, etc)
So basically, when I call res.flash('error','.'), this error displays and everything works as expected. (PS: I'm passing '.' as 2nd argument because I don't want to put the message inside it, because sometimes I want to show a form to the client when it is triggered and it's not gonna look good in the server to pass the whole form as its 2nd arg)

Now, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to insert all the messages into the database (MySQL) and render them when one of them is called.

I tried to do this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
var flash_name = res.locals.flash
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err){
        res.flash('error', '.')
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM flash WHERE flash_name = ?', flash_name, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        //here I pass the "rows" to the view and render the message that I got from the database
        next()
    })
    connection.release()
})
```

});

The database has 3 columns: flash_id, flash_name, flash_message
So therefore, whenever res.locals.flash is passed to the database, its equivalent message should be returned from the database. 
BUT, all I'm getting is database error because here, when I do console.log(flash_name), it's logging this: { error: [ '.' ] } (when 'error' flash is triggered)

The question is, how do I achieve what I want?